# Grouping by column groups on a data frama in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, group-by

I have a data frame with columns for every month of every year from 2000 to 2016

```
    df.columns
```

output

```
    Index(['2000-01', '2000-02', '2000-03', '2000-04', '2000-05', '2000-06',
   '2000-07', '2000-08', '2000-09', '2000-10',
   ...
   '2015-11', '2015-12', '2016-01', '2016-02', '2016-03', '2016-04',
   '2016-05', '2016-06', '2016-07', '2016-08'],
  dtype='object', length=200)
```

and I would like to group over these column by quarters.
I have made a dictionary believing it would be the best method to use groupby then use aggregate and mean:

```
    m2q = {'2000q1': ['2000-01', '2000-02', '2000-03'],
           '2000q2': ['2000-04', '2000-05', '2000-06'],
           '2000q3': ['2000-07', '2000-08', '2000-09'],
                ...
           '2016q2': ['2016-04', '2016-05', '2016-06'],
           '2016q3': ['2016-07', '2016-08']}
```

but

```
    df.groupby(m2q)
```

is not giving me the desired output.
In fact its giving me an empty grouping.
Any suggestions to make this grouping work?
Or perhaps a more pythonian solution to categorize by quarters taking the mean of the specified columns?

Comment: you want to grouby specific columns so you should do something like df.groupby(m2q.get('2000q1')) to get the first quarter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your index to `DatetimeIndex`(example 1) or `PeriodIndex`(example 2).

And also please check [Time Series / Date functionality](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-series-date-functionality) subject for more detail.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


idx = ['2000-01', '2000-02', '2000-03', '2000-04', '2000-05', '2000-06',
   '2000-07', '2000-08', '2000-09', '2000-10', '2000-11', '2000-12']

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12), index=idx, columns=['SAMPLE_DATA'])
print(df)

         SAMPLE_DATA
2000-01            0
2000-02            1
2000-03            2
2000-04            3
2000-05            4
2000-06            5
2000-07            6
2000-08            7
2000-09            8
2000-10            9
2000-11           10
2000-12           11

# Handle your timeseries data with pandas timeseries / date functionality
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

example 1

```
print(df.resample('Q').sum())

            SAMPLE_DATA
2000-03-31            3
2000-06-30           12
2000-09-30           21
2000-12-31           30
```

example 2

```
print(df.to_period('Q').groupby(level=0).sum())

        SAMPLE_DATA
2000Q1            3
2000Q2           12
2000Q3           21
2000Q4           30
```